# QString to double

Tags: qt

```
void setNewValue(const QString& fhStr)
{
  bool ok(false);
  double d = fhStr.toDouble(&ok);
  if (ok) {
      m_newValue = d;
  }
}
```

Passing "23" as `fhStr`; `ok` is always evaluating as false i.e., the converted value (`d`) is never being assigned to the `m_newValue`

Anything wrong here? Using cross-compiler to run on the ARM board.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in your code?

Comment: From a Qt POV it's all correct. For your test case when passing "23" is toInt() instead of toDouble() also sets ok to false?

Comment: @MrEricSir `ok` is evaluating to `true` but still `m_value` still not being updated.

Answer (score 2):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toDouble

You probably have some extra info in your string.  Use qDebug() to see what is going on:

```
#include <QDebug>
// ...
void setNewValue(const QString& fhStr)
{
  bool ok(false);
  double d = fhStr.toDouble(&ok);
  if (ok) {
      m_newValue = d;
  }
  qDebug() << fhStr << ok << m_newValue;
}
```

If you have other information you want to remove from your string, use a QRegularExpression or `.strip()` or some other string operators to get just the number out.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details

Also look at QValidators.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#details
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-lineedits-example.html

Hope that helps.